how to save an animation from the compositor
I rendered an image sequence and imported it into the compositor to apply some grading nodes. How can I save the final result? If it were a single image, I would simply go to the image editor and save it. But how can I do this for an animation consisting of 100 frames without having to re-render everything again?

Short answer : Ctrl+F12. You may want to eat some tutorials to get you started about rendering and compositing.

yeah... I'm through those tutorials and if you read the question again carefully, I asked for a solution that doesn't require rerendering ...

you may look up some tutorials to see whats the difference

Compositing is triggered after rendering. In your case, just do your compositing nodes stuff then Ctrl+F12 (you'll have no scene/empty scene so no render time).
